# Java notify when AWT dispatching thread has executed runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, race-condition

So basically I will be updating the GUI for my application, so I use the static method

> void javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable doRun)

But I wish to put my initialize code in the runnable and the logical code outside. But if I invoke the `invokeLater` method, my main-thread and the AWT thread will be in a race condition, because my main-thread will try invoke my logical code just after the `invokeLater` method has been called, but since the JFrame (in my case) is not initialized yet, so my main-thread will most likely win the race and therefore throw an exception.

I thought I might be able to wait for the runnable to be executed by the Event-Dispatching thread and then notify from the runnable when it has initialized the initialize code. But for some reason, the code below (abbreviated) doesn't work.

For a lightweight application, the runnable is likely to win the race condition, hence not producing any exception, but in my application the initialize code is longer.

**SSCCE:**

```
public class SSCCE {
    private static JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (this) {
                    frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setTitle("JFrame");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    this.notifyAll();
                    System.out.println("Notified all");
                }
            }
        };
        synchronized (r) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting"); // EDIT this line was after the wait method, and therefore it didn't execute.
                r.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected disruption whilst waiting for the \"Event-Dispatching thread\".",e);
            }
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Hello World!"));
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but what's the motivation behind this?

Comment: All Swing GUI code should execute on the Event Dispatch Thread. The point of using the invokeLater() is to add code to the EDT. There is no need to synchronize your Runabble. I really think you are complicating things. Just put all the code in the EDT. If you have a long running task, then you can invoke that task from within your init code after the GUI is already created and made visible.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm creating a application where the GUI will be updated, and invokeLater should run the main-thread asynchronously on the AWT event dispatching thread, but since I'm trying to access the JFrame directly after, it will throw an exception because it hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: Linus, you're telling us the Y part of what sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- your planned code solution -- a plan that may be totally wrong. I want to know the X part, the underlying rationale for needing such a scheme.

Comment: @camickr So, creating a method like `CreateAndShowGUI` is what I should do? And then invoke it from my runnable after the initialize code?

Comment: It sounds as if you should create your GUI, and then when its through creating, in the GUI code, create a background thread, and run your logical code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay, so from within the runnable executed by the Event-Dispatching thread I should initialize another thread where I put my logic code?

Comment: Linus, you want to run the logic code when the GUI has been constructed, right? So it needs to be started from the GUI thread after the GUI has finished being created. Now as to whether it needs to run in a separate thread, I can't say. Only your code can tell for sure. Usually though as far as I understand, a Model class runs on the Swing event thread, but may call other methods off of the EDT.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay, but in my real application, I create a new instance of a class which may throw an exception, so in the main-thread I've created a try/catch block which handles all the exceptions. But if I create the instance directly from the EDT or another thread a unhandled exception error will occur. So I can't compile it.

Comment: `But if I create the instance directly from the EDT or another thread a unhandled exception error will occur.` - so handle the Exception in the other Thread. Again the reason for using a separate Thread is when you have a long running task and you don't want the GUI to become unresponsive. If you need a separate Thread, then you need to handle the Exception in the Thread.

Comment: There are many questions on this site that address Java exception-handling in a multithreaded environment, and you might want to give some of these a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is quite simple: you are calling (well, you were if it worked) `invokeLater` *after* you are trying to `wait` for the result:

```
synchronized (r) {
  try {
    …
    r.wait(); // <- here you are waiting
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    …
  }
}
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r); // <- never reached, you are waiting above
```

So the obvious fix would be to call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);` *first* and `wait` *afterwards*.

---

But that is rather obsolete, there is the method [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(r);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) which does the job of scheduling a `Runnable` in the EDT and waiting for its completion. So you don’t need to program your synchronization and notification by yourself.

---

But note that your lines in your main method following your `invokeLater` are manipulating the UI and hence should be placed within the EDT just like the construction of the `JFrame` as otherwise you are still violating the Swing’s threading policy and still may get race conditions.

Your `main` thread may execute things concurrently to the EDT and it may wait for the UI construction if you wish. But it should *not* manipulate the UI itself. Such manipulation would also contradict your statement that you want to have the “logical code outside” as manipulating a `JFrame` does not belong to “logical code”.